# jetty unknow domain 404 error page

Tags: java, dns, jetty

I have two webapps on one jetty server. Each has own domain, defined in `jetty-web.xml`, for example `example1.com` and `example2.com`. This is working fine. Now, if someone will point some other domain name(let it be `example3.com`) to my server, and tryed to access it by this name - server will not found context configuration for this new domain and will send default responce with list of installed apps. And I need to change this functionality - i want just hide list of my webapps. In [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html#d0e3463) thay suggest use some webapp, named `root`. It is ok, but than i get conflict of names and this default webapp is overriding my applications, if it was deployed last. So my question is - how do i can change this default 404 page for hidding webapp list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jetty 7 - Disable directory list at /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406298/jetty-7-disable-directory-list-at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [to prevent Jetty from showing context related information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202275/how-to-prevent-jetty-from-showing-context-related-information).
Hint: you can even write own implementation of DefaultHandler and inject in in same way as inbuilt is injected, as far as jetty.xml is IoC-style config.